# Total variation of quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have started learning about stochastic integrals and read that ordinary Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral is not applicable as the martingales are of unbounded variation. Consequently the author says that integrals with respect to the quadratic variation of martingale(square integrable continuous) can be defined.So is the total variation of the quadratic variation of martingales bounded?

Comment: The quadratic variation $\langle X\rangle$ of $X$ is by definition the non-decreasing, continuous, predictable process of bounded variation that makes $X-\langle X\rangle$ a martingale.

Comment: @user7924249 So the integral with respect to the quadratic variation is the normal Lebesgue -Stieljes integral right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.